# Postgresql how to store PHP microtime (true)

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel, microtime

I am trying to store PHP microtime to postgres DB, i tried to use timestamp datatype however i got an error.

this is how i am trying to store it to BD (Laravel framework)

```
<?php
    $transactionDbModel = \App\Db\PaymentTransaction::find($transaction->id());
                $transactionDbModel->payment_id = $payment->id();
                $transactionDbModel->type = $transaction->type();
                $transactionDbModel->amount = $transaction->amount()->value();
                $transactionDbModel->currency = $transaction->amount()->currency();
                $transactionDbModel->invoice_number = $transaction->invoiceNumber();
                $transactionDbModel->reference = (string) $transaction->reference();
                $transactionDbModel->status = $transaction->status();
                $transactionDbModel->psp_reference = $transaction->pspReference();
                $transactionDbModel->psp_status = $transaction->pspStatus();
                $transactionDbModel->microtime = microtime(true);
                $transactionDbModel->save();
```

Error:

> Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input
>   syntax for type timestamp: "1481195739.1502" (SQL: insert into
>   "payment_transaction" ("id", "payment_id", "type", "amount",
>   "currency", "invoice_number", "reference", "status", "psp_reference",
>   "psp_status", "microtime", "updated_at", "created_at") values
>   (a6094610-bd37-11e6-84f4-e710a59a6e32,
>   a6072370-bd37-11e6-ab38-ad42705634e1, open, 175, GBP, ,
>   GQX3NITTRZ-20161208111538, done, 8824811960004172, Authorised,
>   1481195739.1502, 2016-12-08 11:15:39, 2016-12-08 11:15:39) returning "id")'

My question is what is the most suitable postgres datatype that can store php microtime(true)

Comment: `select to_timestamp('1481195739.1502')` convert it

Comment: *what is the most suitable postgres datatype that can store php microtime(true)* -- because `microtime(true)` returns PHP's `float`, the `timestamp` type of PostgreSQL is more than enough (it will be even more precise with default compilation settings). Just use some conversion, like @cske suggested.

Comment: @Dahab please exand your question to include all relevant information about how you save your data (orm, models, php codes, etc.) -- you could try to use PHP's `\DateTime` class as it supports microseconds since 5.2.2 & probably supported by major ORMs.

Comment: Ideally you wrangle this into [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) so Postgres can understand it.